# Are there any C compilers that'll warn about using undeclared defines

Tags: c

I came across the situation recently where the following construct

```
#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN
   do_something();
#endif
```

results in 'do_something()' being compiled if neither `BYTE_ORDER` nor `LITTLE_ENDIAN` are defined. Whilst this isn't unreasonable behaviour, I can't find any option on gcc to give me a warning in this situation.

Without a warning you can get into the rather worrying situation where someone can remove an apparently unused header and it will completely change the result of the compilation, because it caused to be included a header that defined those two macros (and defined them differently).

Comment: `man gcc`: `-Wundef Warn if an undefined identifier is evaluated in an #if directive.` So `echo '#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN'|gcc -E - -Wundef` prints `<stdin>:1:5: warning: "BYTE_ORDER" is not defined [-Wundef]`.

Comment: thanks - please make an answer for the points!

Comment: You can require both sides being defined with `#if defined(BYTE_ORDER) && defined(LITTLE_ENDIAN) && BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: But that bloats the source code and hides what should be reported as an error.

Comment: Or perhaps: `#ifndef BYTE_ORDER  #error BYTE_ORDER is not defined`. So you ensure that this bug is detected at compile time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man gcc`:

```
-Wundef
    Warn if an undefined identifier is evaluated in an #if directive.
```

Thus:

```sh
echo -e '#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN\n#endif'|gcc -E - -Wundef
```

Prints:

```
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
<stdin>:1:5: warning: "BYTE_ORDER" is not defined [-Wundef]
<stdin>:1:19: warning: "LITTLE_ENDIAN" is not defined [-Wundef]
```

And it gets even better with `-Werror=undef`.

Comment: given it's not in -Wall, I have  a nasty feeling it might have problems with standard headers

Comment: Everything is better with `-Werror` (Well not at first, but it's good :D)

Comment: @TomTanner Interesting thought. I'd leave it on until it was actually a problem, and then use [diagnostic pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) to either turn it off for problematic headers or just turn it on where I really wanted it.

Comment: @Biffen yeah. giving it a spin anyway, in case i'm being inordinately pessimistic