# How gets an #if Preprocessor conditional which contains a variable resolved without producing an error?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

How does an `#if` Preprocessor stage statement which contain variable of compile time  get resolved at preprocessor stage itself?

Below is the code which runs without any error:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

void main()
{
   int num=10; /* compile time */

#if((num%2)==0)  /* #if is preprocessor stage but has num of compile time why not error here? */
   printf("\nNumber is Even");
#else
   printf("\nNumber is Odd");
#endif 
}
```

Comment: @ prabhu... is it? Hint: change `int num=9;` and try the same again...

Comment: It depends what you mean by "error". It doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any C compilers that'll warn about using undeclared defines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526560/are-there-any-c-compilers-thatll-warn-about-using-undeclared-defines)

Comment: @myaut ya i do know t what i am asking is that how num(compile time variable) is getting resolve at preprocessor stage

Comment: Scientific method: 1) Replace 10 with an odd number and try again. 2) [Observe the result](http://ideone.com/XtQO4C) and scratch your head. 3) Remove the declaration of `num` altogether and try again. 4) [Observe the result](http://ideone.com/rQ3Bss) and scratch your head vigorously. 5) Read the documentation.

Comment: @myaut its not duplicate please dont misguide

Comment: As soon as you declared main as returning `void`, you invoked undefined behaviour, so this could just as well print "Number is a banana" and still be perfectly compliant.

Comment: @Quentin, that remark is not very constructive and also just wrong. At least for C it is implementation defined if it can accept a `main` with a different prototype. And if it doesn't this is a constraint violation (= compile time error) and not undefined.

Comment: @JensGustedt I was pretty sure it was undefined. Well, the joke fell flat, but I learnt something, so thanks !

Comment: There's a reason the preprocessor is called a **pre**processor. That **pre**fix means "comes first".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the evaluation in `#if`, the preprocessor replaces all identifiers that are already defined macros by their appropriate expansion. All identifiers that remain after that have the value `0`.

Comment: can you  please elaborate it.

Comment: `num` is not a defined pre-processor symbol, so it gets a value `0`. `0%2` is `0` so the first `printf` is selected.  The presence of a _compiler_ symbol `num` has no effect.